# let the background-image opaque at the top red bar and transparent at the rest part down below

Tags: css, background-image, opacity

[image]

I want to let the background-image have an `opacity: 1` (opaque) at the top red bar and `opacity: 0.9` (transparent) at the rest part down below.

for now it is:

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-image: url("./LoveLive-SuperStar.png");
    opacity: 0.9;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0;
}

.head {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #94070A;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) says **opacity applies to the element as a whole, including its contents, even though the value is not inherited by child elements. Thus, the element and its children all have the same opacity relative to the element's background, even if they have different opacities relative to one another.**

Comment: You could make the PNG translucent?

Comment: Can you provide a snippet with the markup and all the styles

Comment: png HAS the transculent option but I don't know how to do

Comment: Struggling to understand what you want. You want translucency on everything except the red banner?

Comment: Yes, I want translucency on everything except the red banner

Comment: It would really help if you provided the markup and any other styles you might have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have translucency on everything except the red banner, you could apply your 0.9 opacity only to the direct children of your body and not your body itself. And then override the banner's opacity to full. I would have to see your markup to guarantee this working but you can give it a go:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-image: url("./LoveLive-SuperStar.png");
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0;
}
body > * {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.head {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #94070A;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: I am glad that it works! I learned the `body > * {}` from you, thanks!